# How to create a custom menu with Nextron (electron)

Tags: typescript, next.js, electron

I am trying to create an app using [Nextron](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron) (Electron with Nextjs and Typescript). I already have the bases of my Next app, but when trying to create a custom electron menu bar, I always end up getting errors or incompatibilities with NextJS.

For example, when trying an adapted version of [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-menu-bar-application-electron-react/) solution, the server is not able to get the icon due to errors related with promises, like this one:

`(node:20876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to load image from path (my path)`

That happens when using the public path of my project and also if I put the image in the /main folder.

The reason I want to create this custom menu is to be able to move from external websites back to my app homepage, and to be able to store some data (some of the cases are to store youtube video links into a local 'playlist', or to store words from websites in a 'dictionary'). Iframe is not an option in this case because some of the websites I need do not allow it.

Is there abny way to customize that electron menu using these technologies, or should I try to use vanilla JS / plain React instead and edit my project?

If there is any way to create floating buttons or sidebars when using external websites, please let me know since that would work too, but I think it is not possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement menu from `electron`.

```
const { app, Menu } = require("electron");
```

Ref
https://dev.to/saisandeepvaddi/creating-a-custom-menu-bar-in-electron-1pi3

Comment: But if I'm not wrong, that way I would just be asociating the menu to some html elements, right? Since it is not a 'native' bar, if I move to an external website, the bar will disapear